# request-promise html request behind proxy

Tags: rest, jasmine, protractor, request-promise

iam trying to get response from REST api behind proxy.

When testing manually with browser (chrome, IE), i can get the results from GET request when proxy is configured in the browser.

But when iam tryin to do the same in nodejs with npm package request-promise (inside protractor + jasmine test) iam getting error:
Error: tunneling socket could not be established: statusCode407

here is my code for the test (tried two approaches):

```
'use strict';

describe('test suite', function() {

    it('REST test 1', function(){

        var request = require('request-promise');

        var url = 'https://environment/getId';
        var fullProxy = 'http://myProxy:8080';

        var proxiedRequest = request.defaults({'proxy': fullProxy});
        proxiedRequest.get(url).then(function(response){
            console.log('Response: ' + response);
        }).catch(function(error){
            throw new Error(error);
        });

    });

    it('REST test 2', function(){

        var request = require('request-promise');

        var url = 'https://environment/getId';
        var fullProxy = 'http://myProxy:8080';

        var options = {
            uri: url,
            proxy: fullProxy
        };

        request(options)
            .then(function(response){
                console.log('Response: ' + response);
            })
            .catch(function(err){
                throw new Error(err);
            });

    });

});
```

Thank you for your time and effort!

Comment: Can you check headers, Browser sends some headers by default.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import rp from 'request-promise';

const url = `https://environment/getId`;
const proxiedRequest = rp.defaults({ proxy: 'http://USER:PASSWORD@myProxy:8080' });
this.response = await proxiedRequest.get(url);
```

https://github.com/request/request-promise/issues/130

Comment: It helped me a lot. Thanks mate.